# Need help understanding the formal definitions of $\cap\mathcal{F}$ and $\cup\mathcal{F}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Some context: I'm working through Velleman's $\textit{How to Prove it}$ and am currently at section 2.3.5.

I'm having some trouble grasping the definitions of $\cap\mathcal{F}$ and $\cup\mathcal{F}$. On an intuitive level, it's fairly obvious what each one means:

- The intersection of a family of sets are the elements which are common to all the sets in $\mathcal{F}$.
- The union of a family of sets are all the elements which make up the sets in $\mathcal{F}$.

This intuitive understanding doesn't seem to match up with the formal definitions provided in the book:

- $\cap\mathcal{F}=\{x|\forall x \in \mathcal{F}(x \in A)\}=\{x|\forall A(A \in \mathcal{F} \to x \in A)\}$
- $\cup\mathcal{F}=\{x|\exists A \in \mathcal{F}(x \in A)\}=\{x|\exists A(A \in \mathcal{F} \land x \in A)\}$

Here's how I'm parsing (obviously incorrectly) each statement in english:

- $\cap\mathcal{F}=$ "For every set A, if A is in $\mathcal{F}$ then the element x is in A?" This would make more sense to me if it was something along the lines of $(A \in \mathcal{F} \land x \in A)$... i.e "every set A is in $\mathcal{F}$ and a given element x is in each set A."
- $\cup\mathcal{F}=$ "For some set A, A is in $\mathcal{F}$ and the element x is in that set A." Again, this is doesn't seem to match up with my intuitive understanding of the union concept.

I would appreciate some guidance on how to correctly interpret these formal definitions! Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a misprint in the first formula: $\cap \mathcal F = \{ x \mid \forall A \in \ldots$

Answer (score 1):

> $∩ \mathcal F=$  "For every set $A$, if $A$ is in $\mathcal F$ then the element $x$ is in $A$?"
>
> This would make more sense to me if it was something along the lines of $(A∈ \mathcal F ∧ x∈A)$... i.e "every set $A$ is in $\mathcal F$ and a given element $x$ is in each set $A$."

**NO**: it must be evident from your reading in plain English: "every set $A$ is in $\mathcal F$...". But we do not assert that **every** set must belong to $\mathcal F$.

We need the *conditional* in order to "select" only those $A$ that belong to $\mathcal F$.

---

Similar for union: $x \in A \cup B$ iff $x$ belongs to at least one of $A$ and $B$.

In the same way, $x \in \cup \mathcal F$ iff $x$ belongs to at least one of the elements of $\mathcal F$, i.e. iff for some set $A \in \mathcal F$: $x \in A$.

Try to use the definition to answer the question: "(for $x$ whatever) does $x$ belongs to $\cup \mathcal F$ ?"

Consider $x$: if we find an $A \in \mathcal F$ such that $x \in A$, then it is true that "$x \in A$ and $A \in \mathcal F$, for some $A$".

Thus, we can conclude with: $x \in \cup \mathcal F$.

Answer (score 1):

> - The intersection of a family of sets are the elements which are common to all the sets in $\mathcal{F}$.

Correct, so $x$ will be an element of this intersection iff for every $A\in\mathcal F$ we have: $x\in A$.

In mathematical notation iff $\forall A\in\mathcal F[x\in A]$, leading to: $$\cap\mathcal F=\{x\mid \forall A\in\mathcal F[x\in A]\}=\{x\mid \forall A[A\in\mathcal F\implies x\in A]\}$$

> - The union of a family of sets are all the elements which make up the sets in $\mathcal{F}$.

Correct if "make up" is interpreted as: the union contains all elements of all the sets in $\mathcal F$. This can be reworded as $x\in\cup\mathcal F$ iff for some $A\in\mathcal F$ we have: $x\in A$.

In mathematical notation iff $\exists A\in\mathcal F[x\in A]$, leading to: $$\cup\mathcal F=\{x\mid \exists A\in\mathcal F[x\in A]\}=\{x\mid \exists A[A\in\mathcal F\wedge x\in A]\}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\cap \mathcal F~{ = \{x\mid \forall A\in \mathcal F: x\in A\} \\= \{x\mid \forall A: (A \in\mathcal F\to x\in A)\}}$

It is the set built of $x$ such that if $A$ is an element of $\mathcal F$ then $x$ is an element of $A$.

That is: "The set of elements that are in *every* set that are in $\mathcal F$."

---

$\cup \mathcal F ~{= \{x\mid \exists A\in \mathcal F: x\in A\}\\=\{x\mid \exists A: (A\in F~\wedge~x\in A)\}}$

It is the set of $x$ such that there is an $A$ in $\mathcal F$ and $x$ is in $A$.

"The set of elements that are in *some* set that is in $\mathcal F$."